# Android AutoCompleteTextView with Style ExposedDropDownMenu

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I have AutoCompleteTextView with this style:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
```

I want to change color of outlines
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSILn.png)
. Only what i found is `app:boxStrokeColor` but this is changing color only in focused mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the color state list resource to change the border color for focused, hovered, or unfocused mode.

Create a `color` resource directory under `res`, and add an XML file, named `border_stroke.xml`. The path of this XML would be `res/color/border_stroke.xml`

Now, place a `selector` in `border_stroke.xml` with color values of all modes

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_hovered="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/green" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/pink" /> <!--unfocused-->
</selector>
```

Set this `border_stroke` as color value of `boxStrokeColor` attribute

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/border_stroke"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        ...
        >
```